# Ошибки компоновщика LNK2005 и LNK1169

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, компоновщик

Не доходит как правильно "рассовать" написанный мной код.
Возможно ошибка связана с fstream?

### Файл `main.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Steck.h"

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    file.open("Text.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не найден!";
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }
    Stack1 *st1;
    Stek2 *st2;
    bool done = false;
    int temp;

    while (!done)
    {
        switch (menu())
        {
        case 1: 
            st1->file_input_push_ch(st1);
            st2->file_input_push_nech(st2);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << endl << "Номер состава:";
            cin >> temp;
            if (temp % 2 == 0)
                st1->push_ch(st1, temp);
            else
                st2->push_nech(st2,temp);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            st1->print_ch(st1);
            st2->print_nech(st2);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "  Конец работы. " << endl;
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << endl << " Внимание!!!  Вводите только цифры от 1-го до 4-ёх!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

### Файл `Steck.h`

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FILENAME_H
#define FILENAME_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

ifstream file;

int menu();
class Stack1
{
public:
    Stack1() :ch(0), next(0)
    {
        cout << endl << "Constructor1 working..." << endl;
    }
    ~Stack1();
    void push_ch(Stack1*&, int);
    void file_input_push_ch(Stack1*&);
    void print_ch(Stack1*);
private:
    int ch;
    Stack1 *next;
};

class Stek2
{
public:
    Stek2() :nech(0), next(0) 
    {
        cout << endl << "Constructor2 working..." << endl;
    }
    void push_nech(Stek2*&, int);
    void file_input_push_nech(Stek2*&);
    void print_nech(Stek2*);
    ~Stek2();

private:
    int nech;
    Stek2 *next;
};


#endif // !FILENAME_H
```

### И файл `Stack.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Steck.h"

int menu()
{
    char buf[10];
    int option;
    do
    {
        cout << endl << "1 - Ввести данные с файла." << endl;
        cout << endl << "2 - Ввести данные вручную." << endl;
        cout << endl << "3 - Вывести состояние сортировочного узла" << endl;
        cout << endl << "4 -  Выход из программы." << endl;
        cin >> buf; option = atoi(buf);
    } while (!option);
    cin.get();
    return option;
}

void Stack1::push_ch(Stack1 *&next, int temp)
{
    Stack1 *pv = new Stack1;
    if (temp % 2 == 0)
    {
        pv->ch = temp;
        pv->next = next;
        next = pv;
    }
    else
        delete pv;
}

void Stack1::file_input_push_ch(Stack1 *&next)
{

    int temp;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> temp;
        push_ch(next, temp);
    }
}

void Stack1::print_ch(Stack1 *b)
{
    Stack1 *print = b;
    if (print == NULL)
        cout << endl << " Чётных нет. " << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Чётные номера: " << endl;
        while (print)
        {
            cout << print->ch << "  ";
            print = print->next;
        }
         cout << endl;
    }
}

Stack1::~Stack1()
{
    cout << endl << "Destructor1 working..." << endl;
    while (next)
    {
        Stack1 *p;
        p = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete p;
    }
}

void Stek2::push_nech(Stek2 *&next, int temp)
{
    Stek2 *pv = new Stek2;
    if (temp % 2 != 0)
    {
        pv->nech = temp;
        pv->next = next;
        next = pv;
    }
    else
        delete pv;
}

void Stek2::file_input_push_nech(Stek2 *&next)
{
    int temp;
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file >> temp;
        push_nech(next, temp);
    }
}

void Stek2::print_nech(Stek2 *b)
{
    Stek2 *print;
    print = b;
    if (print == NULL)
        cout << endl << " Нечетных нет. " << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Нечётные номера: " << endl;
        while (print)
        {
            cout << print->nech << " ";
            print = print->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

Stek2::~Stek2()
{
    cout << endl << "Destructor2 working..." << endl;
    while (next)
    {
        Stek2 *p;
        p = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь ***"построить"*** выдаёт следующее:

> Ошибка    LNK2005 "class std::basic_ifstream<char,struct
> std::char_traits > file" (?file@@3V?$basic_ifstream@DU?
> $char_traits@D@std@@@std@@A) уже определен в
> Stack.obj Классы_вариант_1        C:\Users\Семён\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\Классы_вариант_1\Классы_вариант_1\Классы_вариант_1.obj  1
>
> Ошибка    LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или
> более    Классы_вариант_1 C:\Users\Семён\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2015\Projects\Классы_вариант_1\Debug\Классы_вариант_1.exe 1

Может у кого-нибудь был опыт? Отпишитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifstream file;` в .h-файле.
Правило одного определения нарушено.

Мне вообще не нравится идея делать `file` глобальной переменной - но как минимум в .h-файле объявите как

```
extern ifstream file;
```

ну, а в каком-то .cpp-файле уже определяйте

```
ifstream file;
```

Но! честное слово, пересмотрите решение так, чтоб глобальных переменных не было.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы сказали. Заработало!

Comment: Да, еще одну ошибку нашел! В main объектам Stack1 *st1 и Stek2 *st2 надо присвоить NULL, иначе не будет работать функции просмотра.